# JSON and JS repeat check index number (PURE JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript, json, database

I am making a login site via JSON, and I want to check if a username matches with a password (by using array indexes to match username, password and email) but I can't figure out how to see if the username matches with any index number and if there is an index in an array that corresponds with it in the passwords section. I can use indexOf with recursion (function that calls itself) but I have to increment the index checked by 1 which I do not know how to do. (searched for any stuff but I can't find anything)
like this:

```json
{
"usernames": [
"Supa", "Marwan", "Jason", "Jacob",
]
"passwords": [
"placeholder", "placeholder1", "placeholder2", "placeholder3",
]
}
```

```js
function checkDetails(username, password) {
let message = document.getElementById("placeholder");
let password = document.getElementById("placeholder1");
let username = document.getElementById("placeholder2");

//part I am struggling with
let usernames = json.parse("usernames");
let passwords = json.parse("passwords");
message.innerHTML = (username === usernames[/*i want this to increment to check*/]) ? 
message.innerHTML = (password === indexOf(/*I want this to be the index of the one 
index that IS true to the conditional above*/)) ? m
essage.innerHTML = "Success with logging in" :
 message.innerHTML = "Invalid username or password";
```

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket in your `checkDetails` example and have a linebreak in the middle of a variable name (`message`)...

Comment: I assume this is a toy project, because this approach to authentication is totally insecure. There's no need for recursion here. `json.parse` isn't a function, that should be `JSON.parse`. Are you looking for `indexOf`, e.g. `usernames.indexOf(username) >= 0`?

Comment: Ignoring the other problems with your code, it looks like you want to use a long and unreadable ternary expression here for whatever reason and you're therefore looking for a suitable test. Which is simply `data.usernames.indexOf(username) == data.passwords.indexOf(password)` (although you would also have to check if either of them is > -1)

Comment: since the usernames and passwords are stored in arrays and the passwords and usernames for everyone are in the same index, I want it to check the text of every single username in the array, and than find the index number of the correct one and check if the passwords are the same (using your example, I can't check the text of the indexof to see if it is correct and they put it in the input.

Answer (score 0):

As comments attest, your JSON was malformed and this is a completely insecure way of managing a login. That said, here's how you can test for a username, and if it exists, check to see if the appropriate password checks out. In the first line of the function, we normalize the username to be lowercase with any extra space removed.

```js
let json = {
  "usernames": [
    "Supa", "Marwan", "Jason", "Jacob",
  ],
  "passwords": [
    "placeholder", "placeholder1", "placeholder2", "placeholder3",
  ]
}

function checkDetails(username, password) {
  let userindex = json.usernames.findIndex(u => u.toLowerCase().trim() === username.toLowerCase().trim());
  if (userindex === -1) {
    return 'username does not exist';
  } else if (json.passwords[userindex] !== password) {
    return 'wrong password';
  }
  return 'success!'
}

console.log(checkDetails('Supa1', 'placeholder1'))
console.log(checkDetails('Supa', 'placeholder1'))
console.log(checkDetails('Supa', 'placeholder'))
```